# Express.js: 2 PasportJS's deserialize() methods conflict in vhost

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, vhosts

and thank you for viewing this question.
I'm building a service with 3 express apps using `vhost`:

1. For client
2. For moderator
3. For admin (this one not developed yet)

So each one of them uses `Passport.js` with diffetent authentication (diffrent user collections). End every one of them successfully authenticates. The problem is in `Passport's` `serialize()` and `deserialize()` method which overrides previous in another vhost. I call them this way:

**server.js**

```
var app             = express(),
    clientApp       = require('./config/client/express')(db),
    moderatorApp    = require('./config/moderator/express')(db);

app.use(vhost('localhost', mainApp)); 
app.use(vhost('moderator.localhost', moderatorApp)); 
app.listen(config.port);
```

**client/express.js**

```
// some express settings, router settings

// and here I set passport
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// Deserialize sessions
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({
        //....
    }) 
});

// Require necessary strategies
require(path.resolve('config/moderator/strategies/local.js'))();

// Return Express server instance
return app;
```

**moderator/express.js**
here is almost (made some security stuff) same as in `client/express.js` except `Passport's` `deserialize()` method. It looks for a user in `SuperUsers` collection.

**FINALLY ABOUT PROBLEM**

The problem is after authentication passport can't deserialize user from needed collection. I think it overrides previous passport deserialize settings. But if leave only one passport serialize and deserialize method (delete another serialize & deserialize method which overrides prvious) it work totally OK.

**THE QUESTION**
How can I set passport's serialize and deserialize method's in two `vhosts` that it won't conflict with each other???

Please community help me.